# Property binding of value attribute

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 5 and i am currently learning the basics. 
I learnt about template reference variables. But i had a question.
Instead of using template reference variable , i have tried property binding with the "value" attribute of the input element with a class variable , and on button click i tried to log in the class variable, but it is not working. Could you please let me know where am i going wrong﻿.

Here is my code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `

  <input type="text" value="{{greet}}"/>
  <button (click)="logMe()">Click </button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

public greet="";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
logMe()
{
console.log(this.greet);}
}
```

Comment: What you are getting in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will just log nothing because the binding is one-way only. If you want to view the input value in the `greet` variable use `ngModel` instead.

For that import `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts` and change the code in following way:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `

  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="greet"/>
  <button (click)="logMe()">Click </button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

public greet="";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
logMe()
{
console.log(this.greet);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular have an entirely different way for binding form inputs.

I think you are trying to achieve two data binding.

So the angular way of doing this.

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="greet"/>
```

Since we are new, you can use the stackblitzfor posting working angular code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9qubm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html